# how to carry 1 during arithmetic addition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a code that performs simple additions but uses the method where it carries the 1 if the number is larger than 10 (the same way people do additions). I took care of the logic to carry the one, but I'm not sure how to show it in the print. I would like for there to ve a separate row where ion the print where the is a 1 under any column the carry is used here is what I have to far:

```
res_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 15, 18, 9, 3]

for index, i in enumerate(res_list):
    if i > 9 or len(str(i)) == 2:
        res_list[index] -= 10
        if index > 0:
            res_list[index - 1] += 1

final_result = sum(d * 10 ** i for i, d in enumerate(res_list[::-1]))

print(f"\n \t   {n1 : {even_space}d} \n + \t   {n2: {even_space}d} \n \n \t  {'_' * bar_length +
    '_'} \n \t "
    f"     {final_result}")
```

Does anyone know how to do this?